# How do I intergrate 'Facebook Live' on a live WordPress Page?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, live-streaming, embedding

How would you go about embedding facebook live into a wordpress themed website?

Comment: What about Facebook Live are you trying to embed?  An encoder?  A player?  Some sort of video list?

Comment: Hi Brad, I was trying to encode the live-stream but I got it now. Turns on all I had to do was copy and paste the URL from Facebook. Thank you.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question, with some example source code.  This will help others in the future with the same question.